# How to write SQL for column based on different values?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a following table

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1000 | 8800 |
| 1000 | 8810 |
| 1000 | 8820 |
| 2000 | 9900 |
| 2000 | 9910 |

I need to create a following table with Column C . Column C contains values from column B for which the Column A has common value. For Eg: for 1000 there are 3 values 8800, 8810, 8820. So for each combination of 1000 and column B values I need remaining values in Column C. How can I generate following table using SQL?

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 8800 | 8810 |
| 1000 | 8800 | 8820 |
| 1000 | 8810 | 8800 |
| 1000 | 8810 | 8820 |
| 1000 | 8820 | 8800 |
| 1000 | 8820 | 8810 |
| 2000 | 9900 | 9910 |
| 2000 | 9910 | 9900 |
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |

I tried using Concat but was not able to generate column c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to perform self-join.

With sample data:

```
SQL> with test (cola, colb) as
  2    (select 1000, 8800 from dual union all
  3     select 1000, 8810 from dual union all
  4     select 1000, 8820 from dual union all
  5     --
  6     select 2000, 9900 from dual union all
  7     select 2000, 9910 from dual
  8    )
```

Query:

```
  9  select a.cola, a.colb, b.colb colc
 10  from test a join test b on a.cola = b.cola and b.colb not in (a.cola, a.colb)
 11  order by a.cola, a.colb, b.colb;

      COLA       COLB       COLC
---------- ---------- ----------
      1000       8800       8810
      1000       8800       8820
      1000       8810       8800
      1000       8810       8820
      1000       8820       8800
      1000       8820       8810
      2000       9900       9910
      2000       9910       9900

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hierarchical query to eliminate the need for any joins:

```sql
SELECT cola,
       PRIOR colb AS colb,
       colb AS colc
FROM   table_name
WHERE  LEVEL = 2
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
       PRIOR cola = cola
AND    PRIOR colb <> colb;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (cola, colb) AS
  SELECT 1000, 8800 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1000, 8810 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1000, 8820 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2000, 9900 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2000, 9910 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| COLA | COLB | COLC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 8800 | 8810 |
| 1000 | 8800 | 8820 |
| 1000 | 8810 | 8800 |
| 1000 | 8810 | 8820 |
| 1000 | 8820 | 8800 |
| 1000 | 8820 | 8810 |
| 2000 | 9900 | 9910 |
| 2000 | 9910 | 9900 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dDSuPa4k)

Answer (score 0):

You may aggregate all the values into collection per group (`column_a` value) and then perform cross join of this collection to itself to generate all pairs.

```
with agg as (
  select
    column_a,
    collect(column_b) as vals
  from sample
  group by column_a
)
select
  column_a,
  column_b.column_value as column_b,
  column_c.column_value as column_c
from agg
  cross join table(vals) column_b
  cross join table(vals) column_c
where column_b.column_value != column_c.column_value
```

Which produces this output for your data:

| COLUMN_A | COLUMN_B | COLUMN_C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 8800 | 8820 |
| 1000 | 8800 | 8810 |
| 1000 | 8820 | 8800 |
| 1000 | 8820 | 8810 |
| 1000 | 8810 | 8800 |
| 1000 | 8810 | 8820 |
| 2000 | 9900 | 9910 |
| 2000 | 9910 | 9900 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ACnndD_B)